# Occasionally another app opens when i open some app

Tags: windows, taskbar, bug

So actually it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBVwG.jpg

After my last Windows fresh reinstall:
Almost constantly taskbar icons look like this (highlighted as active).
Usually when I try to open some app (Like Steam) instead Skype opens (Or I try to open Discord and Telegram was opened) or I single click on some app and it was opened.

I try to install various builds of MSDN Windows 10 iso's but this problem is still here.

Currently, I'm on 20H2 19042.508
I have the same build and programs installed on my other PC without problems.

Any suggestions why this problem still here? I'm really tired to reinstall various builds and have the same problem.

Comment: Try making the App you want (or ones you do not want) as Hidden Icons. Then see if you can manage this way. Unifi and Samsung Magician seem to be misbehaved and one opens when try to open the other. So it is somewhat application dependent.

Comment: Doesn't work.
https://i.imgur.com/7FIBVp7.png
Seems that this problem arise when I got any notifications in the taskbar.

Comment: I am not sure in this case.  Simply having notifications does not cause this on any of my machines. I will keep checking when I get a chance.

Comment: I got this problem only on my home PC. At work, I got the same build with the same programs installed.
Full Windows reinstall doesn't work (With partition deleting also).

Comment: I have looked around and this is not a common problem (that I can see).  This article discussed some issues with notifications so it may be worth reviewing:  https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-notifications-on-windows-10/